# Human readable string representation of table in Lua

Tags: lua

I am new to Lua and want to print the contents of a table for debugging purposes. I can do that by iterating over the table myself. However, since this strikes me as a very common problem, I expect there must be an out of the box way of doing that or someone must have written a nice library that does that. WHat's the standard way of doing this in Lua?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better or worse, there's no standard. Lua is known for what it excludes as much as for what it includes. It doesn't make assumptions about proper string representations because there's no one true way to handle things like formats, nested tables, function representation, or table cycles. That being said, it doesn't hurt to start with a "batteries-included" Lua library. Maybe consider [Penlight](http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/). Its [pl.pretty.write](http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/api/modules/pl.pretty.html#write) does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

This is an instance of the general problem of table serialization.

Take a look [at the Table Serialization page at lua-users](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization) for some serious implementations.

My throw at it is usually quickly defining a function like

```
function lt(t) for k,v in pairs(t) do print(k,v) end end
```

Comment: I saw that page, but find it hard to believe, that such a common problem get's solved over and over again and in such a verbose fashion.

Comment: that's why a full Lua installation is about 1Mb (opposed to python at 43.3 MB). You have a point, but then again, while you might need the function a lot others might not (think embedding Lua). You don't need to implement it over and over either, just drop it in a file, and `require` it as needed, or put it in the `LUA_INIT` environment variable, which will load it automatically (see the [*standalone* section](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#7) of the Lua manual) .

Comment: @ajmurmann - It's hard to believe, true. But Lua is known for what it excludes as much as for what it includes. It doesn't make assumptions about proper string representations because there's no one way to handle things like formats, nested tables, function representation, or table cycles. That being said, it doesn't hurt to start with a "batteries-included" Lua library. Maybe consider [Penlight](http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/). [pl.pretty.write](http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/api/modules/pl.pretty.html#write) does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the great responses!
I find it very reasonable that this isn't part of the standard library, for the reasons both of you mentioned.

Comment: I was hoping for some small Lua rocks that solve this common problem.
The Penlight library might do it for now, although I was hoping for a smaller library with narrower scope.

Comment: @Corbin - do you want to turn your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it, since I went with Penlight as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

See table.print in https://github.com/rimar/lua-reactor-light/blob/master/util.lua it was probably borrowed from lualogging library